# Looking for an animated movie where Superman is in a coffin sent to the sun

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman, animation

I watched an animation where Superman is in a black coffin and gets sent into the sun. My question is, does anyone know what animation this is from?
Also there was another character who looks like Superman with longer hair, also I think Beast Boy was there too.

Answer (score 8):

While the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187336/82909) has some great suggestions, I'm afraid it's not entirely correct. What you're thinking of is an episode from the 1980's [*Super Friends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Friends). Specifically, the ninth and final season: [*The Super Powers Team: Galactic Guardians*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Super_Powers_Team:_Galactic_Guardians) episode 7: "[The Death of Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_Friends_episodes#Season_9:_1985)."

[image: Superman's coffin being loaded into the ejection chute]

[image: Firestorm watches Superman's coffin drop into the sun]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I took the liberty of adding some links to your answer; if you could find and add an image of the coffin, that would be really great.

Comment: This is definitely the episode that the question made me think of.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it might be one of these:

*Superman: Doomsday* - There is a Superman clone in there, long-haired Supes fights him. Coffin sent to the sun to recharge Supes. No Beast Boy though.

*Justice League vs Teen Titans* - Beast Boy fights Supermen there.

There is also the episode of the Justice League TV show called "Hereafter II", with long-haired bearded Superman:

There is also a movie called *All-Star Superman*, where he also flies into our star:

Comment: One answer per answer please otherwise how do we know what we're voting on for the Id and how do we know which story the OP accepts (if they do).

Comment: So, am I supposed to make 3 answers, one for each possibility?

Comment: That's what I'd do, then you can add more detail into each answer for why it matches the OPs description, see [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) Though you should beware that some people may downvote you thinking you are truing to farm rep or something. Posting one solution per answer helps voters know what they are actually voting on.

Comment: @jo1storm - Yes, that's precisely what you should do if you think there are multiple distinct possibilities. The only time you'd go for a multi-answer spread is if the question isn't clear and you just want to dump off some indistinct possibilities. In this case the "black coffin" should be the uniquely defining feature that allows you to post a single answer.

Comment: @Valorum There is black coffin in two of them and beast boy in one of them. All of them fly into the sun. Not clear enough, sorry.